# How to earn "Inquisitive" badge

Tags: support, badges

I'm not sure it's an error or a bug, I've achieved the target many weeks but I haven't earned this badge.

Snapshot:

[image: 1]

What can I do to earn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, **and maintain a positive question record**.